# How to obtain positive predictive values from multinomial regression?

Tags: r, regression, sensitivity-specificity

For a 2x2 scenario, to determine misclassification we can obtain positive and negative predictive values from a logistic regression model where the outcome is the true value and the exposure is the measured value. I can demonstrate what this might look like in R:

```
set.seed(123)
true <- rbinom(2000, 1, 0.30)
measured <- rbinom(2000, 1, 0.25)
tab <- table(measured,true)
crude.ppv.npv <- tab/rowSums(tab)
mod <- glm(true ~ measured, family='binomial')
model.ppv <- (1) / (1+ (exp(-(coef(mod)[1]+1*(coef(mod)[2]))))) 
model.npv <- (1- ((1)/(1 + exp(-(coef(mod)[1]+0*(coef(mod)[2]))))))
```

My question is how can I extend these equations to obtain the predictive values in a 5x5 scenario. More specifically, the probability of being truly in category X given that you are categorized in category X.

I imagine the model could either be specified as a multinomial model, where all levels of the true and measured exposure are taken into account. Or we could model the measured values separately for all levels of the true exposure.

Here is an example in R.
Say we have two variables with 5 levels each, from which we can create a 5x5 table and find out the probability of being in each true level given that you are categorized as a measured level

```
set.seed(1234)
measured <- as.factor(sample(1:5, 1846, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
true <- as.factor(sample(1:5, 1846, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.19, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.21)))
# make 5x5 table 
tab <- table(measured,true)
tab
# get crude predictive values from the table
tab.prop <- tab/rowSums(tab)
tab.prop
```

So basically I'm trying to obtain each of the cells in the tab.prop table from a regression model. I'm not sure it's possible, any direction would be welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Go through the definition of conditional probability.

$$
P\left(Y = y\vert \hat Y=y\right) $$$$= \dfrac{
P\left(\left(\hat Y = y\right)\bigcap \left(Y = y\right)\right)
}{
P\left(\hat Y = y\right)
}
$$$$=\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\text{Count of How Many Points are Classified } y\text{ and really are } y
}{
\text{Total Number of Classification Attempts}
}
}{
\dfrac{
\text{Count of How Many Points are Classified } y
}{
\text{Total Number of Classification Attempts}
}
}$$$$=\dfrac{
\text{Count of How Many Point are Classified } y\text{ and really are } y
}{
\text{Count of How Many Points are Classified } y
}
$$

Note, however, that multinomial logistic regression does not make hard classifications. Instead, such a model returns the probabilities of class membership. You can map those probabilities to categories, and many people do just assign the label with the highest probability, but those probabilities can be useful. After all, wouldn't you be more comfortable making a decision with probabilities like $(0.95, 0.02, 0.03)$ than $(0.34, 0.33, 0.33)$, despite the fact that both would be mapped to the same category according to a rule that assigns the category with the highest probability?

Answer (score 1):

While it is a good idea to use the derived theoretical positive predictive value as @Dave did, the question did ask how to do this using a regression model:

```
## data from question:
set.seed(1234)
measured <- as.factor(sample(1:5, 1846, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)))
true <- as.factor(sample(1:5, 1846, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.19, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.21)))

#multinomal regression
library(nnet)
multinom_model <- multinom(true~measured)
predicted_values <- predict(multinom_model, newdata=data.frame(measured=factor(1:5)), type="probs")
predicted_values
```

which gives the output

```
          1         2         3         4         5
1 0.2106765 0.1910067 0.1853966 0.2443814 0.1685387
2 0.1868126 0.1868142 0.1923090 0.2170322 0.2170320
3 0.2117343 0.1862289 0.1683639 0.2040815 0.2295913
4 0.1778987 0.2318079 0.1967627 0.1940719 0.1994588
5 0.1983484 0.1763090 0.2314043 0.2011012 0.1928372
```

where the probabilities of correct classification can be read from the diagonal. Notice I compute the probabilities using the `predict` function on a new dataframe, which (for some) is faster than remembering the formula that connects the model parameters to the probabilities.

Comment: This looks like a slick way to do it, but when I tried my own simulation, this method failed. Now, it might be my fault for not coding the simulation correctly (probably is), but some math showing why this regression must give the PPV-oid numbers would be helpful. I think that would dramatically improve this answer (which already does something cool that I hadn’t thought to do and probably does work out).

Comment: This works perfectly for me. If I add additional variables to the model (I want to control for predictors of misclassification), will this work the same? @Dave I have calculated the PPV values by hand, but I want to get them from the model so that I can control for predictors of misclassification.

Comment: @lauraellen You calculated according to the equation in my answer to check if the code here matches, you mean? It could be that I made a mistake in what I did. This does seem like it should work, though I stand by my comment that this post would be improved by showing why this works. After all, this is a statistics website, not a software page. // Your idea of using a regression in order to control for predictors of misclassification is an interesting one and not something I had considered before. I think that warrants it’s own post.

Comment: @Dave the crude values (using the equation in your response) come from the tab.prop table where I take each value and divide it by the total of that row (total measured). For example, a total of 343 are classified as 1 but only 79 are truly 1. 79/343=0.23. Indeed I was thinking of this as a conceptual question but it has turned into more of a coding question!